# Catch All Script in App Engine Python (APP.YAML) does not work in Static Files

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, http-status-code-404, catch-all

I have tried everything but it seems that you cannot get a catch all url...

```
- url: /.*
  script: not_found.py
```

...to work on urls that are based on static directory paths. eg. I can type in www.foobar.com/asdas/asd/asd/asd/ad/sa/das/d and I can get a nice custom 404 page. But if I alter a static path url like www.foobar.com/mydir/mydir/mypage.html, I just get the horrible generic 404....

```
Error: Not Found

The requested URL /mydir/mydir/mypage.html was not found on this server.
```

... I would like to alter whatever catches the url in directory paths and writes the 404. This appears the only way to get a consistent custom 404 page in GAE Python.

Can anyone help? I have written my website from scratch and have a very limited knowledge of Python. Achieving a consistent custom 404 is the only thing I cannot seem to overcome.

EDIT/ADD : OK I've added the kind suggestion of @Lipis , and gone through getting started which which thankfully has given me a much better understanding of classes (I sadly can't vote it up yet). But! I am using a .py script found on the net and I think the NotFound class is interfering with the class that gives my index page, because now my index page is the 404 page specified by the Jinja! I have very little understanding of MainHandler so I may have to give up for now.

```
import os
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

import jinja2


class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get (self, q):
    if q is None:
      q = 'index.html'

    path = os.path.join (os.path.dirname (__file__), q)
    self.response.headers ['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
    self.response.out.write (template.render (path, {}))


class NotFound(webapp.RequestHandler):
      def post(self):
         # you need to create the not_found.html file
         # check Using Templates from Getting Started for more

         jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(
         loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

         template = jinja_environment.get_template('404.html')
         self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))


def main ():
  application = webapp.WSGIApplication ([('/(.*html)?', MainHandler),('/.*', NotFound)], 
                                      debug=True)

  util.run_wsgi_app (application)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main ()
```

Comment: the first two lines of the NotFound class should be under the imports.. as in docs https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/templates

Comment: sorry instead of post(self) > get(self).. I'm updating my answer..

Comment: Make the MainHandler as is in the example bellow.. and change the `application = ` to what I have written there and make sure that you can see your index.html page when you're on homepage and anything else returns the 404.html.. if that works you are OK with the first step.. later you will have to understand how the URL mapping works and what are these things: `/.*`, `/(.*html)?`. They are regular expressions that most likely you'll have to read about them as well :) But one step at the time..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For better understanding I'll make some modifications on the [Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/) example which I assume that you have done it and you made some experiments with it.

It's not a good idea to have the static file for all the not found pages in the `app.yaml` since most likely you would like to show something more dynamic and usually the `- url: /.*` should be handled within your app.

In this [example](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/handlingforms) we are going to add a new `RequestHandler` for all your *not found* pages

```
import jinja2
import os
# more imports

jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
         template = jinja_environment.get_template('index.html')
         self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))

class NotFound(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
         # you need to create the not_found.html file
         # check Using Templates from Getting Started for more
         template = jinja_environment.get_template('not_found.html')
         self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))

application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
                                     [('/', MainPage),
                                      ('/.*', NotFound)], # <-- This line is important
                                      debug=True)
```

But in order to make the jinja2 templates work, follow carefully the modifications that you need to do in [Using Templates section](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/templates) from the Getting Started.

The order in the URL mapping is very important so this catch all regular expression (`/.*`) should be always the last one, because otherwise all the other rules will be skipped.

Comment: Thanks you ever so much. I'm working through this now and I'll let you know how I get on :D

Comment: @Hannah make sure that you went through the getting started tutorial carefully and it works on your computer, and then simply add this NotFound handler and the URL mapping line :)

Comment: @ Lipis I have added more to my original Q :)

Comment: I still don't think it will work for the urls not found in my static directories, whether I specify a /.* in my script or my app.yaml. I need to throw a custom 404 when a file in a static dir is not found.

Comment: @Hannah I don't think that this is very doable or at least in an easy way.. you're mapping a static folder to a specific URL, otherwise you will have to map every single file explicitly and then if everything will fail you'll return your 404 page.. you can see that google supports custom error handling pages.. but 404 is not included.. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Custom_Error_Responses

Comment: OK, at least I shall not drive myself potty over it anymore even though it's rubbish that you can't adapt the script that does the 404 already :) I learnt a bit of regex while puzzling out explicit static files in app.YAML ealier on. Then I did some JavaScript and now it looks like I will learn Python :)

Comment: I understand it now. I was running an entirely static site. As per your guidance I am now using Jinja templates with the app and avoiding static content :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch all URLs, you will have to modify your main request handler in your file "not_found.py" by adding '/.*'.

For example, you can set the file "not_found.py" to:

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.response.out.write("Hello, MAIN!")

application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
                                 [('/.*', MainHandler)], # <--- Add '/.*' here
                                 debug=True)

def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)
```

If you navigate to www.foobar.com/asd/ad/sa/das/d or any other URL, you will see the message "Hello, MAIN!.

Hope it helps. Ask question if needed

Comment: Accept answer if it is useful ;)

Comment: This comment is not that useful.. Read few answers and comments from this question.. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/146027/142717 ;)

Comment: Yes you're right. I'll try to give more explanation next time :S. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Thank you @Littm I did try it but it would not work in the way I had hoped.